# Streaming and recording video with Python

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, video-processing

I thinking about architecture of service with video streaming.
2 people call to each other in browsers with webcams (like group talks in google plus, but only 2 people). Their conversation dumping to server. Server know when conversation was started, when it was finished and which clients communicate.

At the backend I plan to use Python/Django. I don't have any ideas about what to use for streaming/frontend(html5, flash). I want to controle streaming process (dumping, start|stop conversation) using python.

What you can recommend to me?

Comment: Not to be mean, but sometimes people should just be told: if you have to ask this question, the project is over your head.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the following two -

http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/ #For video recording purpose

and

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ #For transmission over the network

Following example using Twisted might be of some help -

http://www.rtmpy.org/index.html